# nginx not showing anything

Tags: nginx, flask, certbot

I seem to have a problem with my nginx.

I just deployed a Flask app on an AWS EC2 instance and linked it to my subdomain (let's call it subdomain.domain.com). Everything was working correctly, my app running on port 5001, I installed nginx to redirect traffic coming through port 80. And I did manage to do it. The problem came when I installed the let's encrypt certificates using certbot.

I did not receive any error message, yet navigating to subdomain.domain.com was no longer doing anything apart from giving me a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I tried several things and check every configuration, recreated the certificates, restarted nginx service, but nothing worked. So I decided to start from scratch, uninstall nginx and reinstall it, but the problem persists.

For further information:

- My EC2 instance accepts requests on port 80 and 5001.
- nginx error log dos not show any error apart from an "aborting" message that just appeared right now
  [image]
- nginx service status shows it's active
  [image]
- Right now I don't have my site symlinked so I should not see it, but I should see Nginx Welcome page which is not the case

  ```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://<aws-private-ip>:5001;
        }
    }
  ```
- UFW firewall shows as inactive, so I understand that is not the problem
- I tried to kill all 80/tcp processes and restart nginx but it did not do a thing
- I tried to use `nginx -s reload` but nothing changed
- This my `netstat plant` on port 80 result
  [image]
- The app is running and the server is indeed up, running and accessible since I can see the app opening subdomain.domain.com:5001 on my browser

Could someone point me towards other things I can try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make nginx redirect to the app running on localhost on port 5001. The problem seemed to be due to default nginx file on sites-available somehow shadowing mine. Now I can navigate to my app using AWS's EC2 public IP address, but for some reason it is not showing the page when I navigate through the domain URL. I don't think it is related to AWS configuration since I have one inbound rule on my security grp allowing for connections from 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80 and I added a registry to my hosted zone for my_subdomain.mydomain.com pointing to the machine's public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

this worked fine for me- Please use this a reference.

How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04

See if you have the same steps done or missed a step.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-6-getting-familiar-with-important-nginx-files-and-directories

Comment: I followed the tutorial but it did not work. Something I noticed that I was doing wrong is that I was deploying the app on ip 0.0.0.0:5001 and using nginx to redirect to 127.0.0.1:5001. I changed the app to be deployed on 127.0.0.1. It still does not work, but I think I'm on the good track. Something else weird I noticed is  that I can see nginx welcome page on the elastic IP of the machine. So if I navigate to the IP directly, I see nginx welcome page, if I do it through my subdomain, I get a connection error. I'm beginning to think that my issue is more on the AWS side.

Comment: All the steps before step (Step 5 – Setting Up Server Blocks (Recommended) is working ok yes.
I just did them now in Azure, result: https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/nginx.jpg . I will test the last steps also and see, but it should work fine as long as there is a valid domain. Great to hear that you are on a good path :)

Comment: Does the domain map to IP (Alias)?

Comment: Ok, I managed to make nginx redirect to the app running on localhost on port 5001. The problem seemed to be due to default nginx file on sites-available somehow shadowing mine. Now I can navigate to my app using AWS's EC2 public IP address, but for some reason it is not showing the page when I navigate through the domain URL. 
I don't think it is related to AWS configuration since I have one inbound rule on my security grp allowing for connections from 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80 and I added a registry to my hosted zone for **my_subdomain.mydomain.com** pointing to the machine's public IP address.

Comment: Correction. It works, my site was just cached and not being displayed. T.T